# How to print Integer alongside String Arduino?

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I am trying to print an integer alongside a string but it's not really working out and am getting confused.

```
int cmdSeries = 3;

Serial.println("Series : " + cmdSeries);// That's where the problem occur
```

In visual basic we used to do it this way:

```
Dim cmdSeries As Integer
Console.Writeline(""Series : {0}", cmdSeries)
```

So i've tried it with Serial.println but it returns this error :
call of overloaded 'println(const char [14], int&)' is ambiguous

Can anyone help my out, I want to achieve this without using any libraries and in a clean way.

Comment: Maybe also look at [this question](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/176/972).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a huge difference between Arduino String class and regular C-string.
The first one overloads addition operator, but there is almost excessive usage of dynamic memory. Mainly if you use something like:

```
String sth = String("blabla") + intVar + "something else" + floatVar;
```

Much better is just using:

```
Serial.print("Series : ");
Serial.println(cmdSeries);
```

Btw, this string literal resides in Flash and RAM memory, so if you want to force using flash only:

```
Serial.print(F("Series : "));
```

But it's for `AVR` based Arduinos only. This macro can save a lots of RAM, if you are using lots of literals.

EDIT:
Sometimes I use this:

```cpp
template <class T> inline Print & operator<<(Print & p, const T & val) {
  p.print(val);
  return p;
}

// ...

Serial << F("Text ") << intVar << F("...") << "\n";
```

It prints each part separately, no concatenations or so.

Comment: Interesting, isn't there any other clean methods, if I have to print 20 values with text it's going to be super difficult hasn't anybody found any solution or haven't even the Arduino Devs though about it?

Comment: Sometimes I'm using overloaded operator<< to do that. I just have to find the right sketch :)

Comment: @The_Little_Cousin Updated. It's using `Print` interface, so it can be used with many other classes. However no formatting support.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```cpp
int cmdSeries = 3;
Serial.println(String("Series : ") + cmdSeries);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this.

```
Serial.println(Series: " + String(cmdSeries));
```